# PHP magic method __destruct

Tags: php

What is the purpose of magic method "__destruct()"
Can anybody explain to about the use of it in real application code?
Not in illustrative example. that makes me confuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, the `__destruct()` magic method has very little use in PHP. It is something inherited from other languages like C++ where you have to manage your own memory and it was wise to cleanup/destroy your own member variables when your object was finished being used. If you did not, you could end up with a memory leak. As PHP handles memory, `__destruct` is just much less necessary. Most examples show the use of `__destruct()` to close a DB connection, but it really doesn't justify the use of a magic method. This magic method simply is just the last function that will be called when the object is about to be destroyed. It is just the complementing function for `__construct()`.